# When will __length_hint__ be inaccurate?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm aware that, technically, you cannot know the length of a Python iterator without actually iterating through it.

The `__length_hint__` method i.e. `it.__length_hint__()` returns an **estimate** of `len(list(it))`.  There's even a [wrapper around this method in the operator module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/operator.py#L185), which says that the method "may over- or under-estimate by an arbitrary amount."

For **finite** iterators, what are the cases where `__length_hint__` will be inaccurate?  If this can't be known, why not?

I don't see any reference to this in [PEP 424](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0424/).

```
>>> obja = iter(range(98345984))
>>> obja.__length_hint__()
98345984

>>> import numpy as np
>>> objb = iter(np.arange(817483))
>>> objb.__length_hint__()
817483
```

I know it's not a great idea to rely on an implementation detail.  But this is a detail that is already explicitly used in a top-level function of the operator module.  Would there be, for instance, specific data structures that would not give possible inaccuracies?

Comment: No; that comment is just saying the hint is allowed to be greater than the ultimate length, and it is also allowed to be less than the ultimate length. In other words, it's not promising *anything*; the hint might be right, but it might not be.

Comment: Suppose you have a function which iterates through a list until it finds something that it is looking for. You know that the number of iterated values will be between 1 and N, so you can guess e.g. N/2, but you have no idea what the actual length will be...

Comment: This is an interesting question. My answer is opinion: PEP 424 is the wrong path for this potentially useful method. It *should be* 1) a number >=0 meaning not only the len is available and reliable but there it is (the returned value) or 2) -1 meaning there is no len available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, anything that is iterating over something that is generated dynamically, rather than iterating over a completed sequence.

Consider a simple iterator that flips a coin, with a head worth 1 point and a tail worth 2 points. It continues to flip the coin until you reach 4 points.

```
def coinflip():
    s = 0
    while s < 4:
       x = random.choice([1,2])
       s += x
       yield ("H" if x == 1 else "T")
```

How long will the sequence be? It could be as short as 2: `TT`. It could be as long as 4: either `HHHH` or `HHHT`. However, in the majority of cases it will be 3: `HHT`, `HTH`, `HTT`, `THT` or `THH`. In this case, 3 would be the "safest" guess, but that could be higher or lower.